# How to restrict the number of characters hoizontally but enable vertical scrolling in textarea in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

How do I restrict the number of characters entered horizontally in the mobile version of Chrome so that if an overflow occurs it should move to the next line(have tried maxlength,cols).But i need to enable vertical scrolling...

```
  <textarea rows="4" cols="108" style="resize: none;" data-role="none">              

       </textarea>
```

I have used this..but here i am getting both a horizontal and vertical scroll bar..is there any way by which i can retain only the vertical scroll bar while restricting the number of characters to a fixed length horizontally ,so that on overflow they move to the next line..I am using jquery mobile, and it need the solution to work in Chrome.

Comment: Are you targeting a specific platform like iOS or general mobile? Mobile Safari has a specific quirks to take into account.

Comment: I am using it for a web based application..i need it to work in chrome